# Detached/attached NDepend windows in Visual Studio not remembering where they should be

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ndepend

NDepend is a great tool, but I'm having problems with the various windows opened by NDepend in Visual Studio 2010. The don't seem to remember where I stick/attach them. I want the Error List and Query Explorer to be stuck at the bottom, and the CQL Query Edit window to the right and so on. But when I reopen visual studio and the solution, these windows are re-opened in what seems to be default places.

**When reopening a solution, I would love for these windows to remember where I put them :)** Anyone else having these problems or is it just me? I have a gazillion VS plugins so my environment may be messed up, but I know it's possible to save the window positions in vsix projects...

Thanks for any help! Love NDepend!

Comment: Up-vote -- yes, I have noticed that!  I never thought to try to solve the problem and have just put up with it as one of those tiny irritants in life, but I would be as interested as you to know if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patrick Smacchia from NDepend team writing.
Thanks for the kind word Johan :)

The fact is that NDepend relies on the VS addin API to integrate in VS, and remenbering panels docking state is not an option with this API.

However, we plan to switch to VS extension API, within the year hopefully, and this will solve that issue.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks Patrick. I thought you were using vsix already, that's why I thought it was a quick fix ;) Consider me a willing alpha tester candidate ;)